# error while downloading components in Android studio

Tags: android

android-studio-ide-171.4443003 running as admin
win7x64

How to turn off https when I first run android studio?)

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot download 'https://dl.google.com/android/repository/android_m2repository_r47.zip': SSL peer shut down incorrectly
, response: 200 OK
Warning: An error occurred while preparing SDK package Android Support Repository: Cannot download 'https://dl.google.com/android/repository/android_m2repository_r47.zip': SSL peer shut down incorrectly
, response: 200 OK.
java.io.IOException: Cannot download 'https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sdk-tools-windows-4333796.zip': SSL peer shut down incorrectly
, response: 200 OK
Warning: An error occurred while preparing SDK package Android SDK Tools: Cannot download 'https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sdk-tools-windows-4333796.zip': SSL peer shut down incorrectly
, response: 200 OK.
java.io.IOException: Cannot download 'https://dl.google.com/android/repository/emulator-windows-4530189.zip': SSL peer shut down incorrectly
, response: 200 OK
Warning: An error occurred while preparing SDK package Android Emulator: Cannot download 'https://dl.google.com/android/repository/emulator-windows-4530189.zip': SSL peer shut down incorrectly
, response: 200 OK.
java.io.IOException: Cannot download 'https://dl.google.com/android/repository/build-tools_r27.0.3-windows.zip': SSL peer shut down incorrectly
, response: 200 OK
Warning: An error occurred while preparing SDK package Android SDK Build-Tools 27.0.3: Cannot download 'https://dl.google.com/android/repository/build-tools_r27.0.3-windows.zip': SSL peer shut down incorrectly
, response: 200 OK.
java.io.IOException: Cannot download 'https://dl.google.com/android/repository/google_m2repository_gms_v11_3_rc05_wear_2_0_5.zip': SSL peer shut down incorrectly
, response: 200 OK
Warning: An error occurred while preparing SDK package Google Repository: Cannot download 'https://dl.google.com/android/repository/google_m2repository_gms_v11_3_rc05_wear_2_0_5.zip': SSL peer shut down incorrectly
, response: 200 OK.
java.io.IOException: Cannot download 'https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sources-27_r01.zip': SSL peer shut down incorrectly
, response: 200 OK
Warning: An error occurred while preparing SDK package Sources for Android 27: Cannot download 'https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sources-27_r01.zip': SSL peer shut down incorrectly
, response: 200 OK.
```

Answer (score 0):

> How to turn off https when I first run android studio

In SDK settings:

[image]

Comment: First run. This tab is not active

Comment: First run or not should make no difference. All paths (like SDK location) are set correctly?

Comment: When I chose path for sdk it opens a form and starts to download these components